# can't convert month number to month date in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a ggplot with different tree types in Spain.

I used that code

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape)
set.seed(123)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
df_long <- pivot_longer(df7, 
                        cols = c(Birch, Palm, Oak), 
                        values_to = "m3",
                        names_to = "Trees")


# Plot
ggplot(df_long,
       aes(
         x = Month,
         y = Integral,
         color = Trees
       )) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("trees in Spain") +
  xlab("Month") +   scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 12, by = 1), limits = c(1,12)) +
  ylab(" m3")
```

But unfortunately the month names are not shown, just the number but I would like to have  the month name

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(df7)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df7, 20))`.

Comment: Also include any libraries you are using to manipulate dates

Comment: Add `labels = month.name` to your `scale_x_continuous`. It will use the built-in `month.name` constant.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use name of a month in x-axis in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30351420/how-can-i-use-name-of-a-month-in-x-axis-in-ggplot2) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69411847/changing-month-from-number-to-full-month-name-in-r or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your months are integers you can use the built in constants `month.abb` and `month.name`

```r
library(dplyr)
df  <- data.frame(month_nums = 1:12)

df  |> 
    mutate(
        month_abb = month.abb[month_nums],
        month_full = month.name[month_nums]
    )
#    MONTH month_abb month_full
# 1      1       Jan    January
# 2      2       Feb   February
# 3      3       Mar      March
# 4      4       Apr      April
# 5      5       May        May
# 6      6       Jun       June
# 7      7       Jul       July
# 8      8       Aug     August
# 9      9       Sep  September
# 10    10       Oct    October
# 11    11       Nov   November
# 12    12       Dec   December
```

If they are dates you can use `format()`:

```r
df  <- data.frame(
    month = seq(from = as.Date("2020-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-12-31"), by = "month")
)

df  |>
    mutate(
        month_abb = format(month, "%b"), 
        month_full = format(month, "%B")
    )
#         month month_abb month_full
# 1  2020-01-01       Jan    January
# 2  2020-02-01       Feb   February
# 3  2020-03-01       Mar      March
# 4  2020-04-01       Apr      April
# 5  2020-05-01       May        May
# 6  2020-06-01       Jun       June
# 7  2020-07-01       Jul       July
# 8  2020-08-01       Aug     August
# 9  2020-09-01       Sep  September
# 10 2020-10-01       Oct    October
# 11 2020-11-01       Nov   November
# 12 2020-12-01       Dec   December
```